# Planning to travel to France from India as solo traveler

Tags: visas, schengen, europe, france, solo-travel

I am currently working in a company in India since 2 years but later this year I am going to Canada to pursue my grad degree.(I am an Indian national) Before I join my university in Canada, I want to travel solo in France for about a week. So, I was wondering if anyone of you had any experience like me?

I am bit worried regarding my visa chances since I have heard being a young unemployed (I will resign from my work by the time I travel) person has detrimental effects on visa chances. Is it true?

About funds, I have around 8k euros in savings which I believe is more than enough for a 7 day small solo trip across France. So, my only concern will be to convince the VO that I am not going to over-stay/disappear in France. Any suggestions regarding this?

Comment: What's your citizenship?

Comment: I have Indian nationality.

Answer (score 2):

It would certainly seem easier to apply for a visa while you're still employed in India or already a resident in Canada.

Any evidence regarding your plans for the next year (e.g. evidence that you have registered at a Canadian higher education institution) should help. If it looks official and you have a Canadian visa, this could be enough. EUR 8000 is more than enough and should weight favorably. A detailed plan and tickets in *and out* of France, while not strictly mandatory would probably help too.

Comment: I have valid Canadian study permit till December 2016( my grad course is of 2 years starting from sept 2014). I also have admission letter from my university and also proof that I have paid the admission fees(not tuition fees) to the university.
So, do you think these will suffice to prove that I am not going to over stay or disappear or something like that?

Comment: @thestarfire It's difficult to predict, I think it should be enough.